# Installing croogo for cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am new in cakephp, I want to install croogo in cakephp 2.3. 
My question :
    where to extract the file https://github.com/croogo/croogo is that in:
   -  cakephp2.3/app / pluging/ and rename the folder to app (not working. error not found admin controller )  or 
   - replace files in cakephp2.3/app /(not working).
sorry for my bad english language: (
please help me and thanks.

Comment: what is the difference between the type of content: blog, page and node

Answer (score 0):

`Croogo` is a `CMS` developed by `Cakephp`... Means `Cakephp` is already there.. Just download `Croogo` and read their documentation... And try few google about CMS...

Comment: merci j'ai installé avec succéss :)